# Inter-processor communication between Linux and RTOS

Tags: linux, ipc, embedded-linux, rtos, imx6

I am using imx6 sabrelite board (cortex A9 quadcore) in which Linux OS running on core0 and RTOS on core2. My task is to establish inter-processor communication between two operating systems. i have gone through Remote processor messaging (RPMsg) in Linux. But,i didn't get much information about its usage. It would be really helpful for me if someone share their experience in this topic or suggest me some other approaches to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share us information regarding the RTOS that is being used.

Comment: Hi, I am using AUTOSAR image in place of RTOS

Answer (score -1):

If you use AMP, this user guide has some details: http://openamp.github.io/docs/2016.04/rpmsg_rtos_layer_user_guide.pdf

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?

Comment: i have gone through the document already. is it possible to port rpmsg framework on RTOS?

Comment: @saravanank : The answer to that may depend on the RTOS and you have chosen not to name that.

Comment: @Clifford Hi, I am using AUTOSAR image in place of RTOS. is it possible to port rpmsg framework ?